# sum over all elements in List while iterating over that exact List

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

Can somebody please help me out with that?

(I know that there is a built-in `sum()` function, this `code` is just an example for the general problem I encountered)

```
def sumlist (lst):
    sum = 0        
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        sum = sum + lst[i]
    return sum
```

And I got this error:

```
sum = sum + lst[i]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'generator'
```

As far as I understood the problem is that `i` is an `generator` within the `for` loop which makes it impossible to add it to the int `sum`.

I also tried  `sum = sum + int(lst[i])` which leads to the following:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'generator'
```

Comment: @Mykola I'm sorry about rejected your edit again and again...

Answer (score 1):

You got it wrong. `i` is not a generator. `i` is an integer.

`lst` is a generator in your case. And you can't access elements in a generator using indices.

One easy fix would be to convert the generator into a list before calling `sumlist`.

For instance:

```
generator_object = (i**2 for i in range(5))
print(sumlist(list(generator_object)))
```

Another possibility is to iterate over the generator without indices.

```
def sumgenerator(generator):
    sum = 0        
    for element in generator:
        sum = sum + element
    return sum
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, got it running now by writing the generator into a list using `list ()`. Thanks!!